# Playframework: IntelliJ ultimate 2018 run freeze while running application

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

Since I updated to the version 182.3911.36,
I'm  experiencing random freeze/crash of the IDE while running my play 2.6 scala app with a simple `sbt run` configuration on ubuntu 16.04.

The IDE will just freeze and I'll have to kill the process to restart it.
Sometimes it just runs fine though which makes the problem quite hard to track. Sbt console works fine as well.

Has anyone experienced such an issue? 
[image: config]

Comment: Does it help when you downgrade to an older version, or upgrade to the latest? Currently the newest 2018.2 version is 182.4323.45 and the newest 2018.3 is 183.2635.13.
Which version of the Scala plugin are you using?

Comment: downgrade works, I'll try the new one thanks, do you talk about ultimate versions?

Comment: There shouldn't be differences between Community and Ultimate versions for this